# How to derefence a copy of a STDIN filehandle?

Tags: perl, reference, stdin, perl-module, filehandle

I'm trying to figure  out how to get a Perl module to deference and open a reference to a filehandle. You'll understand what I mean when you see the main program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib '/usr/local/share/custom_pm';
use Read_FQ;

# open the STDIN filehandle and make a copy of it for (safe handling)
open(FILECOPY, "<&STDIN") or die "Couldn't duplicate STDIN: $!";

# filehandle ref
my $FH_ref = \*FILECOPY;

# pass a reference of the filehandle copy to the module's subroutine
# the value the perl module returns gets stored in $value
my $value = {Read_FQ::read_fq($FH_ref)};

# do something with $value
```

Basically, I want the main program to receive input via STDIN, make a copy of the STDIN filehandle (for safe handling) then pass a reference to that copy to the read_fq() subroutine in the Read_FQ.pm file (the perl module). The subroutine will then read the input from that file handle, process it, and return a value. Here the Read_FQ.pm file:

```
package Read_FQ;

sub read_fq{
my ($filehandle) = @_;
my contents = '';

open my $fh, '<', $filehandle or die "Too bad! Couldn't open $filehandle for read\n";
while (<$fh>) {
# do something
}
close $fh;
return $contents;
```

Here's where I'm running into trouble. In the terminal, when I pass a filename to the main program to open:

`cat file.txt | ./script01.pl`

it gives the following error message: `Too bad! Couldn't open GLOB(0xfa97f0) for read`

This tells me that the problem is how I'm dereferencing and opening the reference to the filehandle in the perl module. The main program is okay. I read that `$refGlob = \*FILE;` is a reference to a file handle and in most cases, should automatically be dereferenced by Perl. However, that isn't that case here. Does anyone know how to dereference a filehandle ref so that I can process it?

thanks. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$filehandle` should already be open - you had opened `FILECOPY`, taken a reference and put it in `$FH_ref`, which is `$filehandle`. If you want to re-open it again use the `<&` argument in `open` or just start reading from it *right away*.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense. So I don't need to re-open filehandle ref again in module. I can just start reading from `$FH_ref` right away. Okay, that's clear. I thought I needed to deference it in order to use it. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want the 3-arg equivalent of

```
open my $fh, '<&STDIN'
```

That would be

```
open my $fh, '<&', $filehandle
```